# Print current section at the beginning of each page

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I am making a resume using the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Author: Timmy Chan
% MARGINS AND SPACING
\RequirePackage[margin=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} % Set Margins
\raggedright % left align no indent
\raggedbottom % top align no indent

% COLOR
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{highlight}{RGB}{61, 90, 128} % CHANGE THIS TO YOUR FAV COLOR https://g.co/kgs/aoqdi7

% BULLET POINTS
\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% SECTION FORMATTING 
\RequirePackage[nostruts]{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{0.5em}{0em}
\titleformat{\section}{\color{highlight} \scshape \raggedright \large}{}{0em}{}[\vspace{-0.75em}\hrulefill]

% SUBSECTION FORMATTING
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0em}{0em}{0em}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{0em}{}[]

% BOLD COMMAND
\newcommand{\skills}[1]{ {\bfseries #1}}

% SUBTEXT
\newcommand{\subtext}[1]{\textit{#1}\par\vspace{-.75em}}

% _____________________________Page Style_________________________________
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Removes all indentation
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\rfoot{\thepage}

% _________________________________Header_________________________________
\fancyhead[L]{{\bf Name} \\ LinkedIn Profile \\ City, State, Zip code}
\fancyhead[R]{Email \\ Phone Number}
```

I want the current section to be printed at the beginning of each new page automatically, just as if using the `\newpage` and `\section{}` command.

However, this should only be printed, but not by using the `\section` command in any way: I do not want the `\section` command "hidden". This is because when viewing the pdf, every time a `\section` command is used, it can be viewed in the page structure of the pdf, and I don't want the same section repeated multiple times in the page structure of the pdf.

Also, note that after adding the following code to the preamble

```
% __________________________________Body___________________________________
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

and compiling, the header interferes with the text in the first line. I can get around this by using the `\hfill` command at the beginning of each page. Is there a more proper way around this? (without loosing any space as well) Here is how it looks like without `\hfill`:

[image]

and with `\hfill`:

```
% __________________________________Body___________________________________
\begin{document}

\hfill
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Why using \section if you don‘t want it? Are you aware of cv-templates at ctan https://ctan.org/topic/cv ? You may also want to have a look at the Overleaf gallery https://de.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cv . You can use that code without using Overleaf.

Comment: Off-topic: packages in preamble you can load with `usepackage{...}`, not need fo load them with `\RequirePackage{,,,}`